# Latex Figure caption

Tags: captions

I am using overleaf.com for writing a paper in IEEE trans template. I use the following code for figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{ABC}

\caption{ABC}

\label{fig_sim} 

\end{figure}
```

The problem I am facing is, after compiling it, the caption is like "Fig. 1 : ABC". But what I need is "Fig. 1. ABC". That is replacing the full colon with a full stop. I used the command `\figurename{ABC}` instead of `\caption` but it didn't solve my problem as the figure number is not shown after I compile.

Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE `\figurename` is just printing `Figure` and has no argument. `\figurename{ABC}` is printing Figure followed by the non-argument ABC. You need the `caption` package for example, with `\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments